# 3 way dimmer switch is a four way switch scenario

Tags: lighting

I put a 3 way dimmer switch in a four way switch situation.  The dimmer works however when one of the four way switches is flipped it disables both the dimmer and the lights that goes with the dimmer.  Have I mis-wired the dimmer?

Comment: What is the wiring sequence of incoming power, 3-way switches, 4-way switches and lights? Where in the sequence is the dimmer? What model dimmer?

Comment: Is the dimmer *made* to work in 3-way switches?  Are you using at a former 4-way location (4 wires to a switch that has 2 black 2 brass screws)?  Have you been able to identify your *traveler* wires?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: The dimmer is made to work in 3-way switches.  Yes, there are two black screws and two brass screws.  I guessed on the traveler wire as it is a black wire.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your local box store and purchase a 4-way light dimmer. They are not inexpensive but they are available and much more affordable then changing the wiring. They are also available online, I found this one: https://www.lowes.com/pd/GE-Bluetooth-15-Amp-Wireless-White-Smart-Rocker-Fan-Control/1000068861

Comment: But you have to make sure they will work in your setup. This example product **requires neutral**. It is possible to have a 3/4/3 setup where the 4 only has travelers + **switched hot** and not neutral, in which case this won't work.